# Ajax.BeginForm is duplicating when the model is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview, unobtrusive-javascript, ajax.beginform

I am writing a PartialView Ajax.BeginForm. This partial is composed by a list of messages and a field to send a new message as showed in the figure below:
[image]

the Partial has the following code:

> Code that List the messages

```
@if (Model != null)
{

    <div class="chat-activity-list" id="listaMensagens">
    @foreach (Inspinia_MVC5.Models.PostComentarios comentario in Model.Where(c => c.Usuarios.UsuEmail.Contains(User.Identity.Name) || (c.Usuarios.UsuId == c.Post.UsuId && (c.UsuariosDestinatario != null && c.UsuariosDestinatario.UsuEmail.Contains(User.Identity.Name)))).ToList())
    {
        <div class="chat-element @(comentario.UsuId == comentario.Post.UsuId ? "right" : "")">
            <a class="@(comentario.UsuId == comentario.Post.UsuId ? "pull-right" : "pull-left")" href="#">
                <img src="/Servicili/Images/a2.jpg" class="img-circle" alt="image">
            </a>
            <div class="media-body @(comentario.UsuId == comentario.Post.UsuId ? "text-right" : "")">
                <small class="@(comentario.UsuId == comentario.Post.UsuId ? "pull-left" : "pull-right") text-navy">@Inspinia_MVC5.Helpers.DateHelper.getTempo(comentario.PosComDataEnvio)</small>
                <i class="fa fa-star @(comentario.UsuId == comentario.Post.UsuId ? "text-success" : "text-warning") "></i>
                <strong>@comentario.Usuarios.Clientes.CliNome</strong>
                <p class="m-b-xs">
                    @comentario.PosComComentario
                </p>
                <small class="text-muted">@comentario.PosComDataEnvio</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
    </div>
}
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

> code of the Form to send a new message

```
<div class="chat-form">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("EnviarMensagem", "OrcamentosServicos", new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "listaMensagens", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary()
        //@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FirstOrDefault().Post.PostOrcamentoServico.FirstOrDefault().PosOrcSerId)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.TextArea("PosComComentario", new { @placeholder = "Digite uma mensagem...", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="text-right">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success m-t-n-xs">Enviar mensagem</button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

In my controller I have the following methods:

> Return the PartialView that will render those comments
>   (PostComentarios)

```
public PartialViewResult EnviarMensagem(HashSet<PostComentarios> lComentarios)
{
    return PartialView(lComentarios); 
}
```

For the [Post] method, I have the following code:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult EnviarMensagem(PostComentarios comentario/)
{
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(comentario.PosComComentario))
     ModelState.AddModelError("PosComComeentario", "Informe um texto para enviar a mensagem.");
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
     return PartialView("ListaMensagens");
   else
     return PartialView();
}
```

And I have another Partial view that is used only to render a new message called ListaMensagens...

**My problem is that, when I try to use Validation, the system is duplicating the main form as showed below:**

[image]

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: is the div `chat-form` in the same partial as the  div `chat-activity-list`?

Comment: Yes, it is. But, the responsible to show the new item is the UpdateTargetId "listaMensagens"

Comment: you're adding the `chat-form` to `listaMensagens` if `ModelState` is invalid when you do `return PartialView();`

Comment: this would be a lot simpler if you just used ajax and json to call an action that would return a new comment row and append it to the list on success, or update error message on fail

Comment: the list and the form are in the same Partial, however, when the message is sent with success, then, the Ajax will insert a new item at chat-activity-list.

Comment: Is that slash here a typo? `EnviarMensagem(PostComentarios comentario/)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see, you are using insertion mode InsertionMode.InsertAfter, which means the results from the Action method will be inserted after the existing data in the form.

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
    return PartialView("ListaMensagens");
else
    return PartialView();
```

In the event that your model is not valid, you are returning the whole Partial View, which is inserted after the existing elements in your form.  This results in placing whole additional copy of the partial view after your existing one, duplicating everything in it including the textbox and button.

Comment: Exactly @John, my problem now is how to do that form with that "logic"

Comment: You could try instead of returning PartialView(), return PartialView(null) (with a null model), and only draw the form if the model is not null, by wrapping the  everything in the using Ajax.BeginForm with a if( Model != null )

Comment: I've done different.. the return is rendering all the screen, even with the list of messages.